# running `org-export-as-html' in emacs batch mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When using `org-export-as-html' in batch mode the html produced from code blocks has no syntax coloring.

How do I enable the syntax coloring in batch mode?

EDIT:

From the terminal I run `emacs --script make.el`.
In make.el I include org and org-html and eventually call `(org-export-as-html 3)`

The following will bold/underline keywords but still no color:

```
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/org/contrib/lisp")
    (require 'htmlize)
    (setq c-standard-font-lock-fontify-region-function 'font-lock-default-fontify-region) ;; fixes bug
    (org-export-as-html 3)
```

EDIT 2:

A couple more things I've tried - they make no difference:

```
    (setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((java .t)))
```

I've also tried loaded my entire .emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 and Org 7.9.2

Comment: Try `emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs ...`

Comment: Hi can you post the code you are using to export html? I guess you are not `require`ing the `htmlize` library which is needed to export syntax highlighted html

Comment: Have you tried loading [htmlize](http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi), e.g. `(load "~/elisp/org/contrib/lisp/htmlize")`. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you use the `color-theme` library, then (for occult reasons about which I have no clue yet) you can have colored outputs through `htmlize` when exporting in batch mode.

For example, evaluating the following code in an org buffer to export makes `htmlize` use colors defined by means of a theme, and that works when exporting both in batch mode and interactively (by creating a temporary frame and setting the appropriate color theme to avoid messing up the frame containing the org buffer to export):

```
(require 'cl)                           ;for `lexical-let'

(add-hook
 ;; This is for org 8.x (use `org-export-first-hook' for earlier versions).
 (make-local-variable 'org-export-before-processing-hook)
 (lambda (backend)
   (add-to-list (make-local-variable 'load-path) (expand-file-name "./etc"))
   (require 'color-theme)
   (color-theme-initialize)

   (when (display-graphic-p)            ;Are we running in interactive mode?
     ;; If so, create a temporary frame to install the color theme used by
     ;; htmlize:
     (lexical-let ((buff (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (current-buffer)))
                   (frame (selected-frame)))
       (setq color-theme-is-global nil)
       (make-frame-invisible frame)
       ;; Schedule deletion of temporary frame:
       (add-to-list
        ;; The following is for org 8.x (earlier versions use other hooks like
        ;; `org-latex-final-hook').
        (make-local-variable 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions)
        (lambda (string backend info) (delete-frame frame)))))

   ;; Install color theme.
   (color-theme-blippblopp)))
```